# Background Image Assistance

Tags: css, image, background

I'm trying to have my billboard image approximately 2200px 965px fix inside of an div expanding the width of the screen and 500px in height, without losing any parts of the image. Is this possible, I have problem completing this task.

```
<div class="billboard"> </div>
```

css:

```
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
display:block;
width:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply add `width: 1140px` to your CSS code to make sure that it doesn't get chopped off at all.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want, background image not getting chopped off, but generating an ugly output.

**Note :** The image I used has exactly the same dimensions as you provided (**2200px** by **965px**)

```css
.billboard {
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 500px;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 500px;
  background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0a/Transjorund_Oulu_2007_05_20.JPG);
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="billboard">ABV</div>
```

Here if the snippet is not working: **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/re53mt8e/)**